# How to Read and validate data of a excel sheet through .NET

Tags: .net, windows

I have a excel sheet contains three columns Name, Email ID and Contact No. I would like to read data from a excel data and check through my code that the Email ID column contains @ sign, Contact No should be of maximum 10 digits, I would like to do these types of validation.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier than interop, you may also use an OleDbConnection.

Here is an [example](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the Interop.Excel namespace if you want to get data from Excel files.

If you want something a bit better than using Interop, I use GemBox.Spreadsheet.  You'll want to use another library if it's something you need to deploy to a computer which doesn't have Excel installed.

You can use regular expressions to validate strings. Read up on the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace to figure that one out.

A simple regular expression to check for at least one @ sign in a string would be:
@"@"

To check that a string consists of exactly 1-10 digits:
@"^\d{1,10}$"